# PHP Script not creating new file or folder

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am testing the Google Drive API using PHP but have not managed to get the My document file on my drive via command line. I have also tried creating a folder using the PHP script provided.

My PHP script runs and requests for the auth code which I get from the url it requests me to access. On pressing enter it looks like its working for a while and then it terminates with no errors. When I go to My Google Drive I do not see any new files or folders there

(Using OSX MAMP and PHP)

Thx

PHP code used

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the APIs Console
    $client->setClientId('clien_id');
    $client->setClientSecret('Secret');
    $client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    //Request authorization
    print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
    print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for access token
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle('My document');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('text/plain');

    $data = file_get_contents('document.txt');

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));

    print_r($createdFile);
    ?>
```